# Iterate aggregate output in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to write this query in mongo-

```
select account, count(*) from OBD_active group by account;
```

I am writing code in java-

```
 DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject() );

        DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("account", 1);
        fields.put("status", 1);
        fields.put("_id", 0);
        DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields );

        DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "count", "$account");
        groupFields.put("total", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$status"));
        DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

        db = Connect.getConnection();
        coll = collection(db, "OBD_active");

        AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate( match, project, group );


        System.out.println("Output is"+output);

  and getting output-



Output is{ "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "result" : [ { "_id" : "relnew" , "total" : 3.0} , { "_id" : "tata" , "total" : 2.0}] , "ok" : 1.0}
```

Result is Ok but I want to iterate this result, how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB javadoc gives the answer: [`AggregationOutput` has a `.results()` method which returns an `Iterable` over the results](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/AggregationOutput.html#results%28%29).

And `Iterable` "means" usage in a foreach loop is possible. As such:

```
for (final DBObject result: output.results())
    // do something with the result
```